# How to define a line's width graduated by its attributes?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, style

I have a line shapefile with lots of lines that have different attribute values. I want to present these lines in different widths according to their attribute values without classes but a graduated symbolization based on each attribute value.

Is there any way of doing this without defining different classes by myself? 
It is intended to create a radial flow map with different line widths as a combination of the following examples: [Creating a Radial Flow Map](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2011/09/06/creating-radial-flow-maps-with-arcgis/) and: [Generating Distributive Flow Maps](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/apl/2012/09/12/generating-distributive-flow-maps-with-arcgis/)

I would prefer to do it with ArcMap, but I am also open to trying it with QGIS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure what you mean when you say "according to their attribute values withot classes", but here's a way to get line weight relating to attribute value in ArcMap.
For your feature class, select Properties->Symbology. Then select Multiple Attributes as your option. Set the first value field to the attribute you want to use to control line weight. Then click Variation by: Symbol Size. This will pop up a new dialog. Select your attribute for the controlling field. Then click classify. This will pop up yet another dialog. Select your method as Natural Breaks. Enter the number of distinct values in your attribute table for Classes. (If you don't know the number of distinct values, it appears you can use the number of entries in the table). This will give you a line width for each unique value. Click OK on each dialog and you're back at your map with a line width per value. Note that the width is not proportional to each value, though.

Comment: This was exactly what I was asking for. Thank you very much!